# How to remove canvas, separator and scrollbar?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

1. I am using Python tkinter for designing purpose.In my UI, I have a
   canvas, a separator, and a scrollbar. While updating, the new canvas
   is appending to the previous one. Can you tell me how to remove the
   previous canvas, separator & scrollbar?

   I tried `separator.destroy()`, `canvas.delete('all')`,
   `self.canvas.delete('all')`, `self.canvas.update_idletasks()`, etc.
2. CODE:

   ```
       from tkinter import *
       import matplotlib
       import pandas as pd
       from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
       from wordcloud import WordCloud
       from matplotlib.figure import Figure

       master = Tk()
       separator3 = Frame(height=618,width=180, bd=4, bg='dodgerblue')
       separator6 = Frame(height=250,width=240, bd=4, bg='dodgerblue')
       separator1 = Frame(height=100,width=100, bd=1,bg='dodgerblue')

       def get():
         Disp_pos =10
         Disp_neg =-12
         w = Scale(separator6, from_=10, to=0,orient=VERTICAL)
         w.set(Disp_pos)
         w.pack(anchor=CENTER,side=TOP,ipady=10,ipadx=10)

         Label1 = Label(separator6, text="")
         Label1.pack(anchor=CENTER, side=TOP)
         f3 = Figure(figsize=(2, 3), dpi=100)
         canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f3, master=separator3)
         Label1 = Label(separator3,text="  WORD  CLOUD ")
         Label1.pack(anchor=CENTER, side=TOP)
         ax3 = f3.add_subplot(111)
         text = 'sample'
         print(type(text))
         ax3.set_wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
         ax3.imshow(ax3.set_wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
         ax3.axis("off")
         canvas2.show()
         canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack( side=BOTTOM,fill=BOTH, expand=1)
         canvas2.draw()
         separator2 = Frame(height=150, width=280, bd=4, bg='dodgerblue')
         scrollbar = Scrollbar(separator2)
         scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=270, fill=Y)
         Label1 = Label(separator2, text=" TEXT ",font=('Times', 12))
         Label1.pack(anchor=CENTER, side=TOP)
         i = 'sample sample sample'
         Re=Listbox(separator2,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)                      
         Re.insert(END, i)
         Re.pack()
         scrollbar.config(command=Re.yview)
         separator2.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=BOTH)

       Button1 = Button(separator1, text='  GET  ', font=('Times', 
                        15,'bold'),command=get,  bg="wheat2",relief=RAISED)
       Button1.pack(anchor=CENTER,pady=5)
       separator1.pack(fill=BOTH,side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
       separator6.pack(fill=BOTH,side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
       separator3.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=BOTH,padx=5, pady=5)
       master.config(bg='white')
       master.title('sample')
       mainloop()
   ```

Comment: **We are not see any GUI on your question!**

Comment: `separator.destroy()` should have removed the separator, but without any code we cannot help you.

Comment: @j_4321 Thank you.kindly go through the code

Comment: So what you want is to clear the content of separators 2,3 and 6 each time you click in get?

Comment: @j_4321 yes,exactly

Comment: @j_4321 clear the contents of separator 2,3 & 6, and then update those fields with new contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the content of a frame, the idea is to destroy all its children. All the children of the frame are stored in the dictionnary `frame.children` (under the form {name: widget})

```
children = list(frame.children.values())
for child in children:
    child.destroy()
```

You can use this to clear the content of separator 2,3 & 6 at the start of `get()`. `separator2` is only defined locally inside `get()` which is inconsistent with the definition of the other frames and means that you create a new `separator2` each time you run `get()`. So I have moved it outside the function, with the other frames.

Here is the modified code:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

master = Tk()
separator3 = Frame(master, height=618,width=180, bd=4, bg='dodgerblue')
separator6 = Frame(master, height=250,width=240, bd=4, bg='dodgerblue')
separator1 = Frame(master, height=100,width=100, bd=1,bg='dodgerblue')
separator2 = Frame(master, height=150, width=280, bd=4, bg='dodgerblue')  # define separator2 outside get()

def get():
    # start by clearing frames
    children = list(separator6.children.values()) + list(separator3.children.values()) + list(separator2.children.values())
    for child in children:
      child.destroy()

    Disp_pos =10
    Disp_neg =-12
    w = Scale(separator6, from_=10, to=0,orient=VERTICAL)
    w.set(Disp_pos)
    w.pack(anchor=CENTER,side=TOP,ipady=10,ipadx=10)

    Label1 = Label(separator6, text="")
    Label1.pack(anchor=CENTER, side=TOP)
    f3 = Figure(figsize=(2, 3), dpi=100)
    canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f3, master=separator3)
    Label1 = Label(separator3,text="  WORD  CLOUD ")
    Label1.pack(anchor=CENTER, side=TOP)
    ax3 = f3.add_subplot(111)
    text = 'sample'
    print(type(text))
    ax3.set_wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
    ax3.imshow(ax3.set_wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
    ax3.axis("off")
    canvas2.show() 
    canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack( side=BOTTOM,fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    canvas2.draw()
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(separator2)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=270, fill=Y)
    Label1 = Label(separator2, text=" TEXT ",font=('Times', 12))
    Label1.pack(anchor=CENTER, side=TOP)
    i = 'sample sample sample'
    Re=Listbox(separator2,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)                      
    Re.insert(END, i)
    Re.pack()
    scrollbar.config(command=Re.yview)

Button1 = Button(separator1, text='  GET  ', font=('Times', 
                15,'bold'),command=get,  bg="wheat2",relief=RAISED)

Button1.pack(anchor=CENTER,pady=5)
separator1.pack(fill=BOTH,side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
separator6.pack(fill=BOTH,side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
separator3.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=BOTH,padx=5, pady=5)
separator2.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=BOTH)
master.config(bg='white')
master.title('sample')
mainloop()
```